# Additive Winters Method on R and SAS

Tags: r, sas

I am trying to forecast time series data using additive winters method.

However, R and SAS show different results.

On R, I use:

```
prediction <- HoltWinters(data)
result <- forecast.HoltWinters(prediction,h=12)
```

And on SAS, I use:

```
proc forecast data=data interval=month method=addwinters seasons=month lead=12
id ~~~;
var ~~~;
run;
```

The result using SAS seems correct. But, then what is the corresponding command on R for additive winters method?

Edited

Data used for forecasting (actual data 99.Jan~14.Dec // forecast 15.Jan~15.Dec)

Result on SAS :

```
              Actual    Forecast
01-Jan-99   9259.51      8601.92
01-Feb-99   9337.21      9058.51
01-Mar-99   11657.19    11046.02
01-Apr-99   11499.78    10897.09
01-May-99   11422.8     11600.51
01-Jun-99   12819.36    12782.72
01-Jul-99   11751.37    12165.52
01-Aug-99   11370       12303.4
01-Sep-99   11966.39    12908.75
01-Oct-99   13449.65    13880.35
01-Nov-99   14196.95    14348.38
01-Dec-99   14955.26    14969.56
01-Jan-00   12162.42    10984.74
01-Feb-00   12676.04    11489.67
01-Mar-00   14429.7     14195.92
01-Apr-00   13522.04    13953.02
01-May-00   14636.76    14484.75
01-Jun-00   15250.94    16064.08
01-Jul-00   14455.66    15058.4
01-Aug-00   14786.88    15053.24
01-Sep-00   15133.38    15900.97
01-Oct-00   15248.07    17314.5
01-Nov-00   14989.07    17781.21
01-Dec-00   14976.56    18225.69
01-Jan-01   12644.93    13337.3
01-Feb-01   13354.07    13619.22
01-Mar-01   14124.89    16184.6
01-Apr-01   12121.11    15335.66
01-May-01   13306.96    15537.87
01-Jun-01   12931.94    16467.38
01-Jul-01   11392.26    14925.84
01-Aug-01   11766.19    14368.53
01-Sep-01   12447.32    14481.53
01-Oct-01   12086.03    15001.03
01-Nov-01   12348.97    14772.19
01-Dec-01   11914.47    14701.57
01-Jan-02   11381.88    10839.12
01-Feb-02   11023.04    11028.48
01-Mar-02   13251.32    12520.25
01-Apr-02   13184.53    11612.98
01-May-02   14173.18    12254.46
01-Jun-02   12894.09    12989.84
01-Jul-02   13395.18    11878.11
01-Aug-02   13959.11    12041.86
01-Sep-02   13900.76    12710.43
01-Oct-02   15084.66    13329.67
01-Nov-02   15196.56    13789.21
01-Dec-02   15026.22    14147.82
01-Jan-03   14319.93    11501.63
01-Feb-03   13337.14    11939.97
01-Mar-03   15378.85    14092.91
01-Apr-03   15720.59    13518.87
01-May-03   14676.09    14578.04
01-Jun-03   15656.33    14915.55
01-Jul-03   15431.71    14316.71
01-Aug-03   15375.27    14732.64
01-Sep-03   17021.08    15369.41
01-Oct-03   18929.67    16468.37
01-Nov-03   18242.09    17180.23
01-Dec-03   19728.69    17628.75
01-Jan-04   18987.12    15125.61
01-Feb-04   19136.97    15539.1
01-Mar-04   21174.86    18695.35
01-Apr-04   21483.36    18528.25
01-May-04   20834.26    19621.23
01-Jun-04   21657.11    20686.71
01-Jul-04   21003.79    20270.47
01-Aug-04   19798.97    20925.57
01-Sep-04   20831.13    22190.79
01-Oct-04   22663.29    23836.84
01-Nov-04   23076.61    24174.2
01-Dec-04   23197.21    25025.53
01-Jan-05   22454.03    21731.48
01-Feb-05   20401.1     21866.56
01-Mar-05   23952.5     25098.28
01-Apr-05   22872.51    24533.26
01-May-05   23122.7     24810.41
01-Jun-05   23707.58    25594.39
01-Jul-05   23235.52    24547.68
01-Aug-05   23342.97    24418.52
01-Sep-05   24519.19    25694.48
01-Oct-05   25352.75    27536.19
01-Nov-05   25826.19    27654.6
01-Dec-05   25631.72    28162.71
01-Jan-06   23257.87    24816.05
01-Feb-06   23786.96    23944.95
01-Mar-06   26840.15    27582.45
01-Apr-06   25590.12    26664.91
01-May-06   27934.51    26842.67
01-Jun-06   27948.81    27800.14
01-Jul-06   25774.35    26879.08
01-Aug-06   27287.19    26692.25
01-Sep-06   29651.25    28147.59
01-Oct-06   28015.96    30135.09
01-Nov-06   30602.31    30291.3
01-Dec-06   28775.38    30850.72
01-Jan-07   28092.56    27374.88
01-Feb-07   26225.13    26986.3
01-Mar-07   30385.84    30827.4
01-Apr-07   29944.46    29712.48
01-May-07   31039.9     30593.05
01-Jun-07   32000.11    31325.1
01-Jul-07   30207.44    29994.54
01-Aug-07   30998.13    30363.94
01-Sep-07   29323.54    32220.92
01-Oct-07   34433.81    32968.07
01-Nov-07   35807.89    34156.91
01-Dec-07   33030.28    34298.51
01-Jan-08   32274.58    31200.85
01-Feb-08   31178.19    30418.1
01-Mar-08   35991.78    35083.73
01-Apr-08   37850.25    34170.39
01-May-08   39383.16    35672.2
01-Jun-08   37258.61    37029.99
01-Jul-08   40961.22    35397.31
01-Aug-08   36610.6 36643.26
01-Sep-08   37428.3 37978.81
01-Oct-08   37111.14    40627.63
01-Nov-08   28841.62    41693.79
01-Dec-08   27117.89    39282.75
01-Jan-09   21133.41    34897.97
01-Feb-09   25397.15    31751.45
01-Mar-09   27890.83    35211.67
01-Apr-09   30326.51    33404.59
01-May-09   27823.84    33501.36
01-Jun-09   32210.05    32349.19
01-Jul-09   31908.46    31186.8
01-Aug-09   28949.63    30135.7
01-Sep-09   33922.43    30290.21
01-Oct-09   33970.03    31586.01
01-Nov-09   33991.61    30370.3
01-Dec-09   36009.62    29647.31
01-Jan-10   30735.42    26918.3
01-Feb-10   33039.4     27826.57
01-Mar-10   37308.94    32196.2
01-Apr-10   39301.01    33015.44
01-May-10   38887.93    33741.51
01-Jun-10   42049.05    35612.44
01-Jul-10   40423.61    35726.38
01-Aug-10   36480.96    34986.86
01-Sep-10   39410.88    37367.16
01-Oct-10   43340.34    39031.72
01-Nov-10   41260.91    38661.84
01-Dec-10   44145.32    38897.31
01-Jan-11   44465.37    35146.56
01-Feb-11   38467.41    37696.88
01-Mar-11   48052.99    43363.08
01-Apr-11   48536.73    45201.8
01-May-11   47331.33    46004.44
01-Jun-11   46736.89    48853.22
01-Jul-11   48950.11    47971.97
01-Aug-11   45792.06    46049.44
01-Sep-11   46510.97    49489.07
01-Oct-11   46613.48    52041.88
01-Nov-11   46012.6     50197.47
01-Dec-11   47743.73    50552.93
01-Jan-12   41200.36    45959.34
01-Feb-12   46316.18    45185.6
01-Mar-12   47329.82    52835.08
01-Apr-12   46094.75    53211.89
01-May-12   46872.36    52057.02
01-Jun-12   47162.61    53158.94
01-Jul-12   44667.68    52034.23
01-Aug-12   43045.18    48203.09
01-Sep-12   45412.54    49934.69
01-Oct-12   47087.76    51093.64
01-Nov-12   47805.25    49055
01-Dec-12   44875.31    49452.67
01-Jan-13   45673.11    43697.99
01-Feb-13   42331.84    44506.55
01-Mar-13   47312.7     49516.61
01-Apr-13   46157.93    49291.2
01-May-13   48307.56    48548.62
01-Jun-13   46690.98    49489.66
01-Jul-13   45829.52    47999.33
01-Aug-13   46311.34    45044.18
01-Sep-13   44650.49    47291.91
01-Oct-13   50480.48    48476.08
01-Nov-13   47905.03    47558.53
01-Dec-13   47981.46    47189.5
01-Jan-14   45568.73    43464.04
01-Feb-14   42913.07    43267.52
01-Mar-14   49067.15    48321.59
01-Apr-14   50267.54    48147.76
01-May-14   47584.12    48637.89
01-Jun-14   47828.26    48909.64
01-Jul-14   48206.77    47766.29
01-Aug-14   46115.64    45890.53
01-Sep-14   47448.11    47196.22
01-Oct-14   51643.42    49854.72
01-Nov-14   46758.67    48593.01
01-Dec-14   49703.66    48130.59
01-Jan-15       44759.45
01-Feb-15       43814.72
01-Mar-15       49267.95
01-Apr-15       49342.67
01-May-15       48905.13
01-Jun-15       49301.49
01-Jul-15       48630.5
01-Aug-15       46651.18
01-Sep-15       47976.66
01-Oct-15       51007.17
01-Nov-15       48718.28
01-Dec-15       49240.15
```

Result on R

```
               data     forecast future forcast   err
1999-01-01  9259.511       NA       NA            NA
1999-02-01  9337.212       NA       NA            NA
1999-03-01 11657.190       NA       NA            NA
1999-04-01 11499.780       NA       NA            NA
1999-05-01 11422.801       NA       NA            NA
1999-06-01 12819.358       NA       NA            NA
1999-07-01 11751.365       NA       NA            NA
1999-08-01 11369.995       NA       NA            NA
1999-09-01 11966.386       NA       NA            NA
1999-10-01 13449.648       NA       NA            NA
1999-11-01 14196.951       NA       NA            NA
1999-12-01 14955.262       NA       NA            NA
2000-01-01 12162.425 10963.92       NA   1198.507902
2000-02-01 12676.042 12175.76       NA    500.282628
2000-03-01 14429.703 14175.51       NA    254.190259
2000-04-01 13522.040 13472.80       NA     49.235633
2000-05-01 14636.755 14770.51       NA   -133.754039
2000-06-01 15250.940 15541.75       NA   -290.810794
2000-07-01 14455.656 14377.46       NA     78.196961
2000-08-01 14786.880 13870.49       NA    916.390527
2000-09-01 15133.379 15148.96       NA    -15.577173
2000-10-01 15248.068 17059.69       NA  -1811.622713
2000-11-01 14989.068 16779.45       NA  -1790.381555
2000-12-01 14976.555 16442.70       NA  -1466.140596
2001-01-01 12644.929 12868.65       NA   -223.718981
2001-02-01 13354.074 13048.03       NA    306.041424
2001-03-01 14124.891 14933.38       NA   -808.487509
2001-04-01 12121.110 13479.32       NA  -1358.212637
2001-05-01 13306.959 13707.80       NA   -400.844060
2001-06-01 12931.941 14162.22       NA  -1230.282198
2001-07-01 11392.257 12530.76       NA  -1138.501630
2001-08-01 11766.192 11423.86       NA    342.333819
2001-09-01 12447.324 11993.03       NA    454.289891
2001-10-01 12086.028 13471.55       NA  -1385.517976
2001-11-01 12348.967 13219.97       NA   -871.000430
2001-12-01 11914.472 13321.13       NA  -1406.656333
2002-01-01 11381.879 10417.64       NA    964.234288
2002-02-01 11023.037 11346.56       NA   -323.525777
2002-03-01 13251.323 12321.06       NA    930.263710
2002-04-01 13184.534 11905.48       NA   1279.057740
2002-05-01 14173.177 14001.67       NA    171.502658
2002-06-01 12894.088 14656.67       NA  -1762.582461
2002-07-01 13395.179 12637.11       NA    758.065234
2002-08-01 13959.110 13009.41       NA    949.695762
2002-09-01 13900.763 14036.51       NA   -135.748007
2002-10-01 15084.659 14863.73       NA    220.924877
2002-11-01 15196.561 15903.81       NA   -707.246220
2002-12-01 15026.217 16128.15       NA  -1101.931263
2003-01-01 14319.931 13481.43       NA    838.499661
2003-02-01 13337.145 14102.41       NA   -765.265480
2003-03-01 15378.850 15372.48       NA      6.374537
2003-04-01 15720.592 14273.46       NA   1447.134391
2003-05-01 14676.092 16432.63       NA  -1756.540721
2003-06-01 15656.327 15441.22       NA    215.102577
2003-07-01 15431.714 15115.57       NA    316.148851
2003-08-01 15375.268 15230.76       NA    144.503101
2003-09-01 17021.082 15552.44       NA   1468.638432
2003-10-01 18929.665 17631.40       NA   1298.266347
2003-11-01 18242.088 19326.67       NA  -1084.581730
2003-12-01 19728.688 19359.64       NA    369.043921
2004-01-01 18987.120 17598.47       NA   1388.648159
2004-02-01 19136.968 18189.86       NA    947.105388
2004-03-01 21174.855 21491.36       NA   -316.505731
2004-04-01 21483.357 20183.60       NA   1299.754303
2004-05-01 20834.259 21848.34       NA  -1014.077179
2004-06-01 21657.111 21992.25       NA   -335.135495
2004-07-01 21003.794 21204.63       NA   -200.831919
2004-08-01 19798.969 20950.95       NA  -1151.977104
2004-09-01 20831.133 20877.28       NA    -46.149235
2004-10-01 22663.289 22251.85       NA    411.442346
2004-11-01 23076.612 22999.03       NA     77.581183
2004-12-01 23197.206 24328.39       NA  -1131.185375
2005-01-01 22454.025 21449.64       NA   1004.380171
2005-02-01 20401.096 21640.68       NA  -1239.583336
2005-03-01 23952.500 23524.71       NA    427.793929
2005-04-01 22872.505 22890.99       NA    -18.486510
2005-05-01 23122.703 23267.51       NA   -144.802484
2005-06-01 23707.576 24174.47       NA   -466.894178
2005-07-01 23235.522 23254.96       NA    -19.441949
2005-08-01 23342.967 22870.11       NA    472.858384
2005-09-01 24519.191 24181.23       NA    337.965616
2005-10-01 25352.748 26140.65       NA   -787.905469
2005-11-01 25826.192 26105.81       NA   -279.613268
2005-12-01 25631.716 27077.73       NA  -1446.009749
2006-01-01 23257.866 24194.64       NA   -936.776079
2006-02-01 23786.956 22624.65       NA   1162.301802
2006-03-01 26840.145 26744.73       NA     95.418194
2006-04-01 25590.123 25676.99       NA    -86.870553
2006-05-01 27934.507 26013.85       NA   1920.659653
2006-06-01 27948.805 28309.63       NA   -360.829132
2006-07-01 25774.350 27450.98       NA  -1676.627852
2006-08-01 27287.195 26055.66       NA   1231.533209
2006-09-01 29651.247 27958.11       NA   1693.133659
2006-10-01 28015.959 30823.49       NA  -2807.535190
2006-11-01 30602.313 29651.13       NA    951.182827
2006-12-01 28775.383 31311.67       NA  -2536.289627
2007-01-01 28092.561 27536.04       NA    556.517402
2007-02-01 26225.125 27221.03       NA   -995.908434
2007-03-01 30385.840 30154.41       NA    231.432827
2007-04-01 29944.456 28972.35       NA    972.101950
2007-05-01 31039.901 30478.98       NA    560.917776
2007-06-01 32000.109 31526.44       NA    473.668100
2007-07-01 30207.444 30790.74       NA   -583.294975
2007-08-01 30998.134 30706.25       NA    291.879960
2007-09-01 29323.535 32263.06       NA  -2939.527254
2007-10-01 34433.813 31243.66       NA   3190.150110
2007-11-01 35807.893 34816.76       NA    991.128671
2007-12-01 33030.276 35846.26       NA  -2815.983126
2008-01-01 32274.575 32238.52       NA     36.057687
2008-02-01 31178.190 31129.25       NA     48.935967
2008-03-01 35991.776 35661.86       NA    329.915414
2008-04-01 37850.247 34475.28       NA   3374.964135
2008-05-01 39383.158 37589.95       NA   1793.211905
2008-06-01 37258.608 39589.48       NA  -2330.868780
2008-07-01 40961.223 36620.78       NA   4340.444733
2008-08-01 36610.603 39949.57       NA  -3338.963377
2008-09-01 37428.303 38687.39       NA  -1259.091344
2008-10-01 37111.140 40533.74       NA  -3422.596296
2008-11-01 28841.617 39607.47       NA -10765.849906
2008-12-01 27117.889 31979.88       NA  -4861.989543
2009-01-01 21133.405 27644.57       NA  -6511.166877
2009-02-01 25397.150 22387.35       NA   3009.803422
2009-03-01 27890.831 27662.03       NA    228.803481
2009-04-01 30326.509 27050.73       NA   3275.782200
2009-05-01 27823.839 29477.87       NA  -1654.030756
2009-06-01 32210.048 28301.91       NA   3908.139593
2009-07-01 31908.462 30434.72       NA   1473.739789
2009-08-01 28949.627 30499.66       NA  -1550.037228
2009-09-01 33922.429 30402.26       NA   3520.168465
2009-10-01 33970.032 34374.39       NA   -404.357352
2009-11-01 33991.607 33598.19       NA    393.418312
2009-12-01 36009.623 34420.02       NA   1589.601521
2010-01-01 30735.415 33334.67       NA  -2599.251378
2010-02-01 33039.402 32965.15       NA     74.251190
2010-03-01 37308.940 36862.55       NA    446.386774
2010-04-01 39301.014 36977.51       NA   2323.506807
2010-05-01 38887.930 37707.63       NA   1180.303807
2010-06-01 42049.045 39827.76       NA   2221.289107
2010-07-01 40423.611 40250.34       NA    173.274211
2010-08-01 36480.955 38538.54       NA  -2057.583644
2010-09-01 39410.882 39656.14       NA   -245.255643
2010-10-01 43340.335 40699.66       NA   2640.673716
2010-11-01 41260.912 41942.63       NA   -681.715646
2010-12-01 44145.320 42531.68       NA   1613.636927
2011-01-01 44465.366 39999.33       NA   4466.034961
2011-02-01 38467.412 45361.87       NA  -6894.456854
2011-03-01 48052.991 45771.24       NA   2281.752290
2011-04-01 48536.725 47504.58       NA   1032.144897
2011-05-01 47331.329 47009.83       NA    321.497724
2011-06-01 46736.893 49169.49       NA  -2432.601487
2011-07-01 48950.113 46038.09       NA   2912.026502
2011-08-01 45792.061 45180.75       NA    611.313263
2011-09-01 46510.965 49057.19       NA  -2546.222479
2011-10-01 46613.480 49573.52       NA  -2960.044793
2011-11-01 46012.595 46467.23       NA   -454.631319
2011-12-01 47743.725 47806.82       NA    -63.096213
2012-01-01 41200.358 44453.27       NA  -3252.907581
2012-02-01 46316.184 42501.10       NA   3815.085492
2012-03-01 47329.817 52426.13       NA  -5096.308337
2012-04-01 46094.754 49134.93       NA  -3040.178282
2012-05-01 46872.357 45850.41       NA   1021.949254
2012-06-01 47162.605 47787.00       NA   -624.397804
2012-07-01 44667.681 46784.05       NA  -2116.369000
2012-08-01 43045.181 42391.67       NA    653.511678
2012-09-01 45412.538 45374.25       NA     38.289905
2012-10-01 47087.760 47283.60       NA   -195.839574
2012-11-01 47805.246 46368.70       NA   1436.545616
2012-12-01 44875.311 48965.89       NA  -4090.578322
2013-01-01 45673.109 42414.70       NA   3258.405745
2013-02-01 42331.837 46014.86       NA  -3683.027124
2013-03-01 47312.704 49031.15       NA  -1718.442144
2013-04-01 46157.925 48228.37       NA  -2070.446905
2013-05-01 48307.560 46304.16       NA   2003.403645
2013-06-01 46690.983 48489.06       NA  -1798.081871
2013-07-01 45829.521 46371.35       NA   -541.833148
2013-08-01 46311.341 43429.56       NA   2881.780145
2013-09-01 44650.486 47776.12       NA  -3125.629701
2013-10-01 50480.484 47573.54       NA   2906.939077
2013-11-01 47905.028 48863.67       NA   -958.637959
2013-12-01 47981.456 48775.63       NA   -794.175950
2014-01-01 45568.727 45598.45       NA    -29.719343
2014-02-01 42913.074 45683.29       NA  -2770.212292
2014-03-01 49067.148 49747.34       NA   -680.195351
2014-04-01 50267.537 49495.11       NA    772.430128
2014-05-01 47584.117 50172.76       NA  -2588.638777
2014-06-01 47828.258 48634.27       NA   -806.008321
2014-07-01 48206.768 47335.90       NA    870.868435
2014-08-01 46115.641 45837.89       NA    277.751142
2014-09-01 47448.108 47293.17       NA    154.933827
2014-10-01 51643.422 50481.77       NA   1161.650876
2014-11-01 46758.667 49832.59       NA  -3073.927652
2014-12-01 49703.658 48358.55       NA   1345.110882
2015-01-01        NA       NA 46585.17            NA
2015-02-01        NA       NA 46080.55            NA
2015-03-01        NA       NA 52692.04            NA
2015-04-01        NA       NA 53175.99            NA
2015-05-01        NA       NA 52635.79            NA
2015-06-01        NA       NA 53139.90            NA
2015-07-01        NA       NA 52640.38            NA
2015-08-01        NA       NA 50266.94            NA
2015-09-01        NA       NA 51632.87            NA
2015-10-01        NA       NA 55208.26            NA
2015-11-01        NA       NA 52790.88            NA
2015-12-01        NA       NA 54319.06            NA
```

Comment: Can you please edit your post to show the input time series and the SAS result you deem correct? (The difference is most likely due to differences in initialization, or in how smoothing parameters are chosen internally.)